# THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error: gl.getProgramInfoLog Must have an compiled fragment shader attached

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

I am trying to visualize some particles and modify their appearance using shaders. Really primitive task to be honest, but I seem to be in a pickle right here...
The error contains some code, but I don't understand how is it relevant to me. Is it trying to show me some low-level APIs of some sort?
I have the following file:

```
"use strict";
function ParticleVisualization(boardRadius, bucketSize, type, startAmount){
    var self = this;
    
    //create geometry
    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    var numberOfBoardSlots = Math.pow(boardRadius * 2 + 1,2)*bucketSize;
    var posistionBufferAttr = new THREE.BufferAttribute (new Float32Array(numberOfBoardSlots*3),3);
    var visibilityBufferAttr = new THREE.BufferAttribute (new Float32Array(numberOfBoardSlots),1);
    geometry.addAttribute('position', posistionBufferAttr);
    geometry.addAttribute('visible', visibilityBufferAttr);
    var positions = geometry.getAttribute( 'position' ).array;
    var visibility = geometry.getAttribute( 'visible' ).array;
    
    var attributes = {
        visible: {type: 'f', value: visibility }
    };
    
    //calculate the postion of all resources
    var idx = 0;
    for (var jj = (-boardRadius); jj <= (boardRadius); ++jj) {
        for (var ii = (-boardRadius); ii <= (boardRadius); ++ii) {
            for (var kk = 0; kk < bucketSize; kk++) {
                var startPos = { x: ii + Math.random() - 0.5, y: jj + Math.random() - 0.5, z: -1  };
                positions[idx]   = startPos.x;
                positions[idx+1] = startPos.y;
                positions[idx+2] = startPos.z;
                idx += 3;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (var ii=0;ii<numberOfBoardSlots;++ii) {
        if (ii%bucketSize < startAmount) {
            attributes.visible.value[ii] = 1.0;
        }
        else{
            attributes.visible.value[ii] = 0.0;
        }
    }
    
    //get the code for the shaders
    var vertShader = "      \
        attribute float visible; \
        void main() {       \
            vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 ); \
            gl_PointSize = max(1.0,( 300.0 / length( mvPosition.xyz )));\
            if(visible != 1.0) {gl_PointSize = 0.0;} \
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;   \
        }                   \
    ";
    
    var fragShader = "                  \
        uniform sampler2D texture;      \
        void main() {                   \
            gl_FragColor = texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord ) * vec4(.9,.1,.1,.4); \
        }                               \
    ";

    var texture;
    //create material based on type
    switch(type){
        case 'Resource':
            texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "/assets/resourceSprite.png" );
            break;
        case 'Carrion':
            texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "/assets/carrionSprite.png" );
            break;
    }
    texture.flipY = false;
    
    var uniforms = {
        texture: { type: "t", value: texture }
    };
    
    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: uniforms,
        attributes: attributes,
        vertexShader: vertShader,
        fragmentShader: fragShader,
        blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
        depthTest: true,
        transparent: true
    });

    self.pointCloud = new THREE.PointCloud( geometry, material );
    
    //position is the array position that is the start of the board slot
    //(i.e., if there are 5 resources per board slot, this is the first of the 5 for that board slot,
    //and the following 4 positions are the others at that board slot)
    self.addParticle = function(position){
        //we really just make one of the already existing particles visible
        var visibility = self.pointCloud.geometry.attributes.visible;
        for(var visIdx=0;visIdx<bucketSize;++visIdx){
            if (visibility.array[position+visIdx] === 0.0) {
                visibility.array[position+visIdx] = 1.0;
                visibility.needsUpdate = true;
                //only show one!
                return;
            }
        }
    };
    
    //position is the array position that is the start of the board slot
    //(i.e., if there are 5 resources per board slot, this is the first of the 5 for that board slot,
    //and the following 4 positions are the others at that board slot)
    self.getParticleCountAtPosition = function(position){
        var visibility = self.pointCloud.geometry.attributes.visible;
        var count = 0;
        for(var ii=0;ii<bucketSize;++ii){
            if (visibility.array[position+ii] == 1.0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    };
    
    //position is the array position that is the start of the board slot
    //(i.e., if there are 5 resources per board slot, this is the first of the 5 for that board slot,
    //and the following 4 positions are the others at that board slot)
    self.removeParticle = function(position){
        //we really just hide one of the particles to be hidden
        var visibility = self.pointCloud.geometry.attributes.visible;
        for(var ii=0;ii<bucketSize;++ii){
            if (visibility.array[position+ii] == 1.0) {
                visibility.array[position+ii] = 0.0;
                visibility.needsUpdate = true;
                //only hide one!
                return;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I get the following big fat error:

```
THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 35715 false gl.getProgramInfoLog Must have an compiled fragment shader attached. <empty string> THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() fragment
ERROR: 0:88: 'texture' : function name expected1: #version 300 es
2: #define varying in
3: out highp vec4 pc_fragColor;
4: #define gl_FragColor pc_fragColor
5: #define gl_FragDepthEXT gl_FragDepth
6: #define texture2D texture
7: #define textureCube texture
8: #define texture2DProj textureProj
9: #define texture2DLodEXT textureLod
10: #define texture2DProjLodEXT textureProjLod
11: #define textureCubeLodEXT textureLod
12: #define texture2DGradEXT textureGrad
13: #define texture2DProjGradEXT textureProjGrad
14: #define textureCubeGradEXT textureGrad
15: precision highp float;
16: precision highp int;
17: #define HIGH_PRECISION
18: #define SHADER_NAME ShaderMaterial
19: #define GAMMA_FACTOR 2
20: uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
21: uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
22: uniform bool isOrthographic;
23: 
24: vec4 LinearToLinear( in vec4 value ) {
25:     return value;
26: }
27: vec4 GammaToLinear( in vec4 value, in float gammaFactor ) {
28:     return vec4( pow( value.rgb, vec3( gammaFactor ) ), value.a );
29: }
30: vec4 LinearToGamma( in vec4 value, in float gammaFactor ) {
31:     return vec4( pow( value.rgb, vec3( 1.0 / gammaFactor ) ), value.a );
32: }
33: vec4 sRGBToLinear( in vec4 value ) {
34:     return vec4( mix( pow( value.rgb * 0.9478672986 + vec3( 0.0521327014 ), vec3( 2.4 ) ), value.rgb * 0.0773993808, vec3( lessThanEqual( value.rgb, vec3( 0.04045 ) ) ) ), value.a );
35: }
36: vec4 LinearTosRGB( in vec4 value ) {
37:     return vec4( mix( pow( value.rgb, vec3( 0.41666 ) ) * 1.055 - vec3( 0.055 ), value.rgb * 12.92, vec3( lessThanEqual( value.rgb, vec3( 0.0031308 ) ) ) ), value.a );
38: }
39: vec4 RGBEToLinear( in vec4 value ) {
40:     return vec4( value.rgb * exp2( value.a * 255.0 - 128.0 ), 1.0 );
41: }
42: vec4 LinearToRGBE( in vec4 value ) {
43:     float maxComponent = max( max( value.r, value.g ), value.b );
44:     float fExp = clamp( ceil( log2( maxComponent ) ), -128.0, 127.0 );
45:     return vec4( value.rgb / exp2( fExp ), ( fExp + 128.0 ) / 255.0 );
46: }
47: vec4 RGBMToLinear( in vec4 value, in float maxRange ) {
48:     return vec4( value.rgb * value.a * maxRange, 1.0 );
49: }
50: vec4 LinearToRGBM( in vec4 value, in float maxRange ) {
51:     float maxRGB = max( value.r, max( value.g, value.b ) );
52:     float M = clamp( maxRGB / maxRange, 0.0, 1.0 );
53:     M = ceil( M * 255.0 ) / 255.0;
54:     return vec4( value.rgb / ( M * maxRange ), M );
55: }
56: vec4 RGBDToLinear( in vec4 value, in float maxRange ) {
57:     return vec4( value.rgb * ( ( maxRange / 255.0 ) / value.a ), 1.0 );
58: }
59: vec4 LinearToRGBD( in vec4 value, in float maxRange ) {
60:     float maxRGB = max( value.r, max( value.g, value.b ) );
61:     float D = max( maxRange / maxRGB, 1.0 );
62:     D = clamp( floor( D ) / 255.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
63:     return vec4( value.rgb * ( D * ( 255.0 / maxRange ) ), D );
64: }
65: const mat3 cLogLuvM = mat3( 0.2209, 0.3390, 0.4184, 0.1138, 0.6780, 0.7319, 0.0102, 0.1130, 0.2969 );
66: vec4 LinearToLogLuv( in vec4 value ) {
67:     vec3 Xp_Y_XYZp = cLogLuvM * value.rgb;
68:     Xp_Y_XYZp = max( Xp_Y_XYZp, vec3( 1e-6, 1e-6, 1e-6 ) );
69:     vec4 vResult;
70:     vResult.xy = Xp_Y_XYZp.xy / Xp_Y_XYZp.z;
71:     float Le = 2.0 * log2(Xp_Y_XYZp.y) + 127.0;
72:     vResult.w = fract( Le );
73:     vResult.z = ( Le - ( floor( vResult.w * 255.0 ) ) / 255.0 ) / 255.0;
74:     return vResult;
75: }
76: const mat3 cLogLuvInverseM = mat3( 6.0014, -2.7008, -1.7996, -1.3320, 3.1029, -5.7721, 0.3008, -1.0882, 5.6268 );
77: vec4 LogLuvToLinear( in vec4 value ) {
78:     float Le = value.z * 255.0 + value.w;
79:     vec3 Xp_Y_XYZp;
80:     Xp_Y_XYZp.y = exp2( ( Le - 127.0 ) / 2.0 );
81:     Xp_Y_XYZp.z = Xp_Y_XYZp.y / value.y;
82:     Xp_Y_XYZp.x = value.x * Xp_Y_XYZp.z;
83:     vec3 vRGB = cLogLuvInverseM * Xp_Y_XYZp.rgb;
84:     return vec4( max( vRGB, 0.0 ), 1.0 );
85: }
86: vec4 linearToOutputTexel( vec4 value ) { return LinearToLinear( value ); }
87: 
88:                           uniform sampler2D texture;              void main() {                               gl_FragColor = texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord ) * vec4(.9,.1,.1,.4);         }
```

Comment: Don't use `texture` as a name for a uniform. Use `tex`, for example.

Comment: @prisoner849 thanks, that single-handedly solved the issue! Answer to get reputation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better not to use `texture` as a name of a uniform, as `three.js` internally substitutes it and uses as a function.

See this: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram.js#L707L728

Comment: what do you mean? can you explain clearly?

Comment: @USMANHEART in other words, `texture` is WebGL2.0 function.

Comment: i didnt use the word texture and im still getting the error.